# VM network interface issues on CentOS 8

Tags: centos, networking, network-interface, kvm

I am using a machine with CentOS 8 to create VM. Everything is working fine and now with the initial DHCP setup for VM instances.  I want to change one of my vm instances network settings from DHCP to a static IP on network outside the server. Not much experience with this stuff and just trying to get things working.

When I change to a static IP, The server can only be reached from the console so something is wrong here..

UPDATE:

From the web interface on port 9090, I clicked on networking,`virbr0` for details, then clicked on the IPv4 line so I could add a static route to the virbr0 bridge for the network I want..

`10.2.0.0  16  10.2.0.1`

When my vm instance start up I still can't ping anything..

There are two network devices defined on the CentOS 8 vm server:

```
 enp2s0 10.2.0.104/16 CentOS 8 running VM
 virbr0 192.168.122.1/24 VM instance use this and this device uses `vnet0` port

[yep@per ~]# nmcli connection show
NAME    UUID                                  TYPE      DEVICE
enp2s0  d7ebe444-8fc9-4e13-a05a-c4f95302ce1d  ethernet  enp2s0
virbr0  73935ce6-e170-4293-b322-f0f5ce878b66  bridge    virbr0
vnet0   b35c73a8-acc6-4787-a96f-044a875a79ed  tun       vnet0
```

I used the web interface on port 9090 and my iso image to create a new VM with the following networking:

```
Name    Device  Connection  Forwarding mode State
default virbr0  System      NAT             active

Overview

General
Persistent yes
Autostart <checked> Run when host boots

IPv4 Address
Address 192.168.122.1
Netmask 255.255.255.0
DHCP Range 192.168.122.2 - 192.168.122.254
```

After installing my CentOS VM which is configured for DHCP during the installation everything is working fine and I can ping the outside world. I can only get to the
VM from the host server because of the `192.168.122` space that it resides in.  I need
systems from `10.2.0` and `10.2.2` to have access to the VM instance running on IP `192.168.122.218`.

Networking for the VM:

```
Type    Model type  MAC Address        IP Address          Source   State   
network virtio      52:54:00:ba:de:f5  192.168.122.218/24  default  up
```

What I want to do is change the VM instance on `.218` from DHCP to a static IP address (`192.168.122.218` -> `10.2.2.31`) which is on the network the server is on.  Anyhow, the problem creeps in when I try to change the IP address of the VM to `10.2.2.31`.  After changing to a static IP `10.2.2.31` and restarting the VM, the VM instance is not working on the new IP.

So, I thinking I need to add a bridge?? or adding a port to `virbr0` so that the VM can be seen by machines on `10.2.0` and `10.2.2`. I've tried a few different things here but always manage to screw the whole system up. Any ideas here?? All I need to do is make the VM space visible to other parts of the network so other machines can access to VM machine...spent a number of hours on this so far and not getting anywhere..

Comment: You'll probably have to change the forwarding mode (not NAT anymore) and/or the interface it's attached to (not virbr0 anymore) with a new network to create in libvirt (not default anymore) etc. There's documentation to read for this, so you understand the networking concepts, how to do this in libvirt or possibly on the web interface with libvirt as backend.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I tried a few things with NAT without any luck and found it's easiest to do a `macvtap` solution where you change the network interface on you WM to use macvtap so that the VM acts like it's on its host's network.

Comment: Hello GoinOff, can you kindly post How did you make your VM setup with static IPs? I have two VMs on RHEL 8 host and they both need to be talking to different subnets (The host server has multiport card and cables connect to diff switches etc.). I want the ability to backup and restore/move VMs in case of server failure in addition to network config.